# Realm Migration - Expected Declaration error

Tags: swift, realm

I am adding the basic Realm migration code to my appdelegate:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    schemaVersion: 1,

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
    // a schema version lower than the one set above
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
        }
})

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration
let realm = try! Realm()
```

and this line:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

is throwing a Expected declaration error. Am I missing something?

Comment: *import RealmSwift* at the top? That code should appear within *applicationDidFinishLaunching* as well.

Comment: I am importing RealmSwift and it is in appDidFinishLoading

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact code into a working project and made one change; updated schemaVersion to 2 and then ran the code and it worked perfectly. That would tell me your error lies elsewhere in the project - quite possibly you're missing a trailing }. If you are, the if (oldSchemaVersion <1) would be outside that block and would throw that error. Ensure your closures are in place and if so I would suggest using the cocoaPods.app to reinstall Realm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check - I always use pods to install the dependencies though.